# Clear React child input value from parent using functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to clear child functional component from parent after setting redux state

Here's my code

```
const ParentContainer = (props) => {
    const onKeyDown = (keyPressed) => {
        if (keyPressed.key === 'Enter' && keyPressed.currentTarget.value.length > 0) {
            props.addMail(keyPressed.currentTarget.value);
            keyPressed.target.value = ''

        }
    }
    return (<Child onKeyPressDown={onKeyDown} />)
}
```

On child component

```
const Child = (props) => {
    return (<Input placeholder="Add text list"
        fluid onKeyDown={
            props.onKeyPressDown
        }
    />)

    }
export default Child
```

Actually when I press `enter` text stays , I would like to delete it.

I tried `keyPressed.target.value = ''`  in parent component but it's not working

Comment: With ReactJS, we typically use `setState()` and control components this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce state in the Parent component. Then pass the state value to the input, and provide an onChange handler when the input changes. This is called a controlled component and you can read more about it here.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

```js
const ParentContainer = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const onKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.currentTarget.value.length > 0) {
      props.addMail(event.currentTarget.value);
      setValue('');
    }
  };
  return <Child value={value} setValue={setValue} onKeyPressDown={onKeyDown} />;
};
```

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <Input
      fluid
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(event) => props.setValue(event.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={props.onKeyPressDown}
      placeholder="Add text list"
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleReset = () => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach(
    input => (input.value = "")
  );
  this.setState({
    itemvalues: [{}]
  });
};
```

I found the answer on this , hope it help
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clear-input-values-of-dynamic-form-in-react/